# Say, I have two girlfriends. Which one would be more appropriate to say, "I love them equal" or "I love them equally."

Tags: difference, adverbs

Honestly,the two sentences look identical to me. I have a feeling that there’s a slight difference between, "I love my two girlfriends equal" and "I love my two girlfriends equally."

Comment: I love them both equally.

Comment: The word you're considering tell us the about how much you love, so it must be an adverb, i.e., the type of word that modifies a verb. Can you tell which of *equal* and *equally* is an adverb?

Answer (score 1):

You could say "My love for them is equal", "I love them both an equal amount" or you could say (as you suggest) "I love them equally"  but your first example ("I love my two girlfriends equal") is not normal usage, and wouldn't be considered correct by any teacher.